# Text runs across page width in Drupal Tweme

Tags: drupal

I have used other content management system but recently switched over to Drupal. I am building a website with Tweme responsive template with Drupal 7 but the problem is: The text runs across the page width of the website without stopping. I mean the text isn't flowing down and keeps on running endlessly across the page width.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: I guess people will need some code and/or screenshots in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with the div width.

Do one thing, put the content inside text here & check if that works.

Sample code will help pin-pointing the problem.